# Delete EntireRow that has a specific cell value

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to use this VBS code to delete an entire row that has a specific cell value, but it gives an error when I try to find the value and select the row:

```
Set xc = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xc.Visible = false
xc.displayalerts=false
Set xp = xc.WorkBooks.Open ("C:\Users\Shahim\Desktop\test.xlsx")
Set xs = xp.Worksheets(1)

Set xc = xs.find(what:="Vtest",lookat:=xlwhole).select

Set xr = xc.ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

xr.selection.delete
xp.save
xp.close()
```

Comment: It should be giving you an error much earlier: `set xp=xc.WorkBooks.Open "C:\Users\Shahim\Desktop\test.xlsx"` needs parens around the workbook name.

Comment: Parenthesis are not required as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx example inline.

Comment: Can you advise where in your code the error is occurring? Can you also include how you declare your variables. Seems to be that you can't set a range at the same time as triggering the select event. I would remove the select so `xc` is the range of the first find. and then just do `xc.ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete` which will accomplish your intent. You will probably have to build in some error checking in the case where you dont find the search string. Regards.

Comment: @nbayly This is VBScript, not VBA. Parentheses *are* required here.

Comment: Ahh, I stand corrected. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a number of issues:

1. You need parentheses around function calls returning a value:

   ```
   set xp=xc.WorkBooks.Open("C:\Users\Shahim\Desktop\test.xlsx")
   ```
2. `Find()` operates on a range, not a sheet (`xs.find(...)` is invalid).
3. You can't use named parameters in VBScript (`what:="Vtest"` is invalid).
4. You need to define all Excel constants you're using:

   ```
   Const xlWhole = 1
   ```

Taking all of that into consideration, try the following:

```
' Define constants...
Const xlWhole = 1

Set xc = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xc.Visible = false
xc.displayalerts=false

' Use parens when calling functions...
set xp = xc.WorkBooks.Open("C:\Users\Shahim\Desktop\test.xlsx")

set xs = xp.Worksheets(1)

' Use Find() with a range (column A here, change as needed).
' Specify params by position, not name.
set xc = xs.Range("A:A").find("Vtest", , , xlwhole)

If Not xc Is Nothing Then
    xc.EntireRow.Delete
End If

xp.save
xp.close()
```